7Zip4Powershell is not working with ADO agent
I am trying to install the below powershell module to compress the file with password through AzureDevOps pipeline
 Install-Module -Name 7Zip4Powershell -Repository PSGallery -Force

But while running the below command its not working , its not putting zipped file under the path
Compress-7Zip -Path $SASUri_FilePath -ArchiveFileName "$scriptPath\$SASUri_FileName.zip" -Format SevenZip -Password $key

error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
| '/agent/_work/1/s/Runbook/Scripts/stblog_20240415_SAS.zip'. File
| name: '/agent/_work/1/s/Runbook/Scripts/stblog_20240415_SAS.zip'
| at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path,
| Boolean isDirError)    at

can some one help?

@thoemmi please help module reference https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/7Zip4Powershell/2.0.0

The error message is self-explanatory, "Could not find file", $SASUri_FilePath doesn't point to a folder or file.

i tired same path with another command its was working but this command dont have password parameter @SantiagoSquarzon
Compress-ZipArchive -Path $SASUri_FilePath -Destination "$scriptPath$SASUri_FileName.zip"

As you are using the self-hosted agent, could you please try the Compress-7Zip command on your agent locally to check if it works? I have tried on the Microsoft hosted windows agent, and it works. But on the Microsoft hosted ubuntu agent, I got an error saying that Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' . It seems some dependencies are needed for the   Compress-7Zip command.

I agree with @Miao Tian-MSFT, It works in Windows hosted agent, If you are using Self hosted agent, Check if the file exists in the path in your powershell code and then run your  script like below:-
$fileFullPath = "C:\agent\_work\1\s\Runbook\Scripts\stblog_20240415_SAS.zip"
if (Test-Path $fileFullPath) {
    Write-Host "File exists at: $fileFullPath"
} else {
    Write-Host "File does not exist at: $fileFullPath"
    exit 1 
}
Write-Host "SASUri_FilePath: $SASUri_FilePath"
Write-Host "scriptPath: $scriptPath"

if (-not (Test-Path $SASUri_FilePath)) {
    Write-Host "SASUri_FilePath is not pointing to a valid location."
    exit 1  
}

if (-not (Test-Path $scriptPath)) {
    Write-Host "scriptPath is not pointing to a valid location."
    exit 1  
}

Write-Host "Before compression, SASUri_FilePath: $SASUri_FilePath"
Write-Host "Before compression, scriptPath: $scriptPath"

Compress-7Zip -Path $fileFullPath -ArchiveFileName "$scriptPath\$SASUri_FileName.zip" -Format SevenZip -Password $key

If you are not using Self-Hosted agent and your zip file is in the Repository or downloaded as artifact use the Predefined variables to specify the correct File path.
My Azure Devops yaml code:-
trigger:
- master 
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest' 

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Install-Module -Name 7Zip4Powershell -Repository PSGallery -Force
      $SASUri_FilePath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/temp.zip"
      $scriptPath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/output"
      $SASUri_FileName = "temp"
      $key = "silicon" 
      if (-not (Test-Path $SASUri_FilePath)) {
          Write-Host "File does not exist at: $SASUri_FilePath"
          exit 1        }
      Write-Host "SASUri_FilePath: $SASUri_FilePath"
      Write-Host "scriptPath: $scriptPath"
      Compress-7Zip -Path $SASUri_FilePath -ArchiveFileName "$scriptPath\$SASUri_FileName.zip" -Format SevenZip -Password $key

Output:-

